# this is my first experience with mui, I can't export normally import { DehazeIcon} from "@mui/icons-material"; gives error (

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my first experience with mui, I can't export normally `import { DehazeIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";` gives error. My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.93",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.7"
  }
}
```

My `Header.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { DehazeIcon} from "@mui/icons-material";

//.....

 <div></div>
      <DehazeIcon/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

And error:

[image]

I can't understand what the error is, 4 mui doesn't suit me, I don't want to react to version 17 either.

Comment: Try `import DehazeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Dehaze';`. And please check [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=+Dehaze&selected=Dehaze)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong name, MUI icons don't have the `Icon` suffix. You can find a full list of the icons [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons)

Instead, import like this:

```
import { Dehaze } from @mui/icons-material
```

Or you can change the name its refered to by importing like this:

```
import { Dehaze as DehazeIcon } from @mui/icons-material
```

You can also import from the default export of the individual module, like Enfield li added in a comment. See the [usage guid here](https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#usage)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like below.

```
import DehazeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Dehaze';
```